# calculating $C_G(a)$ when $a\in G=S_3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $a\in G$. $C_G(a)=\{g\in G | ga=ag\}$ is called the center of $a$ in $G$.

In order to understand this theorem I'm trying to find $C_G(a)$ for all $a\in G=S_3$.

As I understand:

$$ C_{G}\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\left\{ g\in G\,:\,g\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3
\end{pmatrix}g\right\} =S_{3}$$

I understand the logic behind it but what would be the way to prove it formally?

How to calculate formally:

$$ C_{G}\left(\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}\right)=\left\{ g\in G\,:\,g\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 3 & 2
\end{pmatrix}g\right\}$$

Answer (score 1):

The first part, that $C_{S_3}(e)=S_3$ follows from the fact that $e$ commutes with everything.

$S_3=\{e,(12),(13),(23),(132),(312)\}$.

You can check that $C_{S_3}(23)=\{e,(23)\}$.  For instance,  $(12)(23)\neq(23)(12)$.  There are three more to check.

Comment: I don't follow you.  Aren't there 4 more elements (besides the identity)?

Comment: Sorry, I'm still not understanding.  What does $(12)(13)$ have to do with $C_G(23)$?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. oops.   It's a typo.

Comment: Ok, now I get it!  Thanks